# Trying to return array from Fortran to Matlab with mex, getting empty array instead

Tags: matlab, fortran, mex

So, I'm trying to return a an array of numbers from 1-n.

```
#include "fintrf.h"

C     Gateway routine
      subroutine mexFunction(nlhs, plhs, nrhs, prhs)

C     Declarations
      implicit none

C     mexFunction arguments:
      mwPointer plhs(*), prhs(*)
      integer nlhs, nrhs


      mwPointer mxGetPr
      mwPointer mxCreateDoubleMatrix
      mwPointer mxGetM, mxGetN
      mwPointer mrows, ncols
      mwSize size
      mwPointer x_ptr, y_ptr
      integer  x_input,i
      real*8, allocatable :: vec(:)
      x_ptr = mxGetPr(prhs(1))
      mrows = mxGetM(prhs(1))
      ncols = mxGetN(prhs(1))
      size = mrows*ncols

      x_ptr=mxGetPr(prhs(1))
      call mxCopyPtrToReal8(x_ptr,x_input,size)

      allocate (vec(x_input))

      do i=1,x_input
        vec(i)=i
      end do

      plhs(1) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, x_input, 0)


      y_ptr = mxGetPr(plhs(1))
      call mxCopyReal8ToPtr(vec,y_ptr,x_input)



      deallocate ( vec )
      return
      end
```

I then call the mex file in fortran here

```
mex testingvec.F
Building with 'gfortran'.
MEX completed successfully.
a=testingvec(10);
```

and then find

```
a=[]
```

Can someone give me some help on this? If someone can give me some example code how to return a matrix as well, that would be sweet.

Thanks guys.

edit: new installment of the code. Still trying to get some help.

```
#include "fintrf.h"

C     Gateway routine
      subroutine mexFunction(nlhs, plhs, nrhs, prhs)

C     Declarations
      implicit none

C     mexFunction arguments:
      mwPointer plhs(*), prhs(*)
      integer nlhs, nrhs


      mwPointer mxGetPr
      mwPointer mxCreateDoubleMatrix
      mwPointer mxGetM, mxGetN
      mwPointer mrows, ncols
      mwSize size
      mwPointer x_ptr, y_ptr
      integer  i
      mwSize sizeone, x_input 
      integer*4 izero 
      real*8, allocatable :: vec(:)
      x_ptr = mxGetPr(prhs(1))
      mrows = mxGetM(prhs(1))
      ncols = mxGetN(prhs(1))
      size = mrows*ncols
      sizeone=1 
      izero=0 

      x_ptr=mxGetPr(prhs(1))
      call mxCopyPtrToReal8(x_ptr,x_input,size)

      allocate (vec(x_input))

      do i=1,x_input
        vec(i)=i
      end do

      plhs(1) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(sizeone,x_input,izero)



      call mxCopyReal8ToPtr(vec,mxGetPr(plhs(1)),x_input)



      deallocate ( vec )
      return
      end
```

Comment: Try setting the literal constant input variables (i.e. `1` and `0`) of `mxCreateDoubleMatrix` to variables with proper type, and passing those to the function. I've had problems with this before. `mxCreateDoubleMatrix` expects `mwSize` type input, which can have different signature as a literal constant.

Comment: Correction: the first two arguments should be `mwSize`, and the final `ComplexFlag` should be `integer*4`, per the [doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxcreatedoublematrix.html)

Comment: how do I get those value out of my array? I tried to do this but it crashes  mrows = mxGetM(mxGetPr(vec))
      ncols = mxGetN(mxGetPr(vec))
      size = mrows*ncols

Comment: I meant using `mwSize sizeone, x_input; integer*4 izero; sizeone=1; izero=0; mxCreateDoubleMatrix(sizeone,x_input,izero)`

Comment: Hi, I tried that, I'm still getting the empty array. Maybe it has to do with how I'm copying my vector into it? call mxCopyReal8ToPtr(vec,y_ptr,x_input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were both declaration problems and issues with calls to mex functions. Here's a solution, which assumes that the input is an integer-valued double giving you the length of the output vector (assuming that this is what you wanted).

```
#include "fintrf.h"

C     Gateway routine
      subroutine mexFunction(nlhs, plhs, nrhs, prhs)

C     Declarations
      implicit none

C     mexFunction arguments:
      mwPointer plhs(*), prhs(*)
      integer*4 nlhs, nrhs


      mwPointer mxGetPr
      mwPointer mxCreateDoubleMatrix
      mwSize mxGetM, mxGetN
      mwSignedIndex mrows, ncols
      mwSize size, x_input, sizeone
      mwPointer x_ptr, y_ptr
      integer*4  i, izero, x_int
      real*8, allocatable :: vec(:)
      real*8 :: x_dbl

      sizeone = 1
      izero = 0



      !check input/output syntax
      if (nrhs /= 1) then
        call mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("MATLAB:testingvec:rhs",
    >            "Exactly 1 input variable required.")
      end if
      if (nlhs /= 1) then
        call mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("MATLAB:testingvec:lhs",
 >            "Exactly 1 output matrix required.")
      end if


      x_ptr = mxGetPr(prhs(1))
      mrows = mxGetM(prhs(1))
      ncols = mxGetN(prhs(1))
      size = mrows*ncols

      call mxCopyPtrToReal8(x_ptr,x_dbl,sizeone)
      x_input = int(x_dbl)

      allocate (vec(x_input))

      do i=1,x_input
        vec(i)=i
      end do

      plhs(1) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(sizeone, x_input, izero)

      y_ptr = mxGetPr(plhs(1))
      call mxCopyReal8ToPtr(vec,y_ptr,x_input)



      deallocate ( vec )
      return
      end
```

I introduced a check for the number of input/output variables (to be updated in the actual program). And I introduced an auxiliary `x_dbl` which might or might not be necessary. This version reads the `double` input given to your function, and truncates it to get `x_input`.

Comment: Thank you. I just realized that the type would be real, which 10.00000000 is something that you can not iterate on for a loop or use as a length.

Comment: Actually, iteration up to a real works both in matlab and in fortran (although `gfortran` throws a warning saying `Deleted feature: End expression in DO loop [...] must be integer`), and both truncate the value of the real bound to integer. The length is a larger problem, because if a function/subroutine expects a variable of different kind, it will misinterpret its value.